# Prove that $\sqrt{n}(Y_n-p)/\sqrt{Y_n(1-Y_n)} \rightarrow n(0,1)$ in distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_i,i=1,2,...,$ be independent Bernoulli(p) random variables and let $Y_n= \frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i=1}^n X_i$.

Prove that $\sqrt{n}(Y_n-p)/\sqrt{Y_n(1-Y_n)} \rightarrow n(0,1)$ in distribution.

My attempt:

I can show that $\sqrt{n}(Y_n-p)/\sqrt{p(1-p)} \rightarrow n(0,1)$ in distribution. Thus, if I can show that

$$\frac{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}{  \sqrt{Y_n(1-Y_n)} } \to 1$$ in probability, then Slutsky's thorem allows me to finish. But I don't know how to prove the above converges in probability.

Comment: Do you have access to either the weak or the strong law of large numbers?

Comment: Yes, I know them. How to use them here?

Comment: Since $Y_n \to p$ both in probability (weak law) and almost surely (strong law), you can pick either to show that $g(Y_n) \to g(p)$ for $g(x) = \sqrt{p(1-p)}/\sqrt{x(1-x)}$.